# List component continually re-renders

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I feel like this is likely due to  me not understanding the flow of React, but I've been struggling to figure it out. Have an infinite scroll list.

if `Row` is outside of `Scroller` it works fine.

However, if `Row` is inside of `Scroller`, it results in the component constantly re-rendering. I was hoping to pass a list into `Scroller` from the parent component with around a thousand items, but in order to do that, I need `Row` in `Scroller` to be able to access the props. Whats the best way to go about this?

```
import React from "react";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const Scroller = (randomArray) => {
  const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
    <div className={index % 2 ? "ListItemOdd" : "ListItemEven"} style={style}>
      {randomArray[index]}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <AutoSizer>
      {({ height, width }) => (
        <List
          className="List"
          height={height}
          itemCount={1000}
          itemSize={35}
          width={width}
        >
          {Row}
        </List>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  );
};

export default Scroller;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think I have an idea...

[Render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render) can be a bit confusing, but they're essentially `children` components that are functions. Meaning, the direct child of `List` **must** be a function that accepts an object of parameters and returns JSX. See this [react-window gist](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/39ee223c7503a834afc1c2e94df27fc5#file-current-api-js) for more information regarding passing in data to `List` and accessing `data` from within the child function.

Here's a working demo:

[image: Edit Virtual Window Custom Data]

By design, this child function is supposed to be re-rendered to add/remove items from the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as the user scrolls up/down. To view this behavior, right click on an element, like `Season Id`, within in the codesandbox window and click on "Inspect" -- you may need to do this twice to focus on the targeted element -- then while the mouse is hovered over the codesandbox render window, scroll down. What you'll notice is that items are dynamically added/removed based upon the scroll direction. So if you're expecting this child function to NOT be re-rendered when the window is scrolled, then you probably shouldn't be using a virtualized list and, instead, should be using pagination.

---

**Example.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const Example = ({ dataList }) => (
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
      <List
        className="List"
        height={height}
        itemCount={dataList.length}
        itemData={dataList}
        itemSize={265}
        width={width}
      >
        {({ data, index, style }) => {
          const dataItem = data[index];
          return (
            <div
              className={index % 2 ? "ListItemOdd" : "ListItemEven"}
              style={style}
            >
              <h1>Season Id: {dataItem.seasonId}</h1>
              <h2>Form Id: {dataItem._id}</h2>
              <h2>Start Month: {dataItem.startMonth}</h2>
              <h2>End Month: {dataItem.endMonth}</h2>
              <h2>Send Reminders: {dataItem.sentReminders.toString()}</h2>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </List>
    )}
  </AutoSizer>
);

export default Example;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Example from "./Example";
import dataList from "./data.json";
import "./styles.css";

render(<Example dataList={dataList} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue is the scroller consistently re-renders regardless of whether or not I'm scrolling. The re-render isn't an issue otherwise.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can get a better idea of what you're trying to do and the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Think I got it actually, thanks. Needed to pass data into `<List>` instead of trying to access it directly.